# what is equivalent to do.call(rbind, list)?

Tags: r

In my real data I got  `warning number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)` ,though my list has a unique number of cols, when I used `do.call("rbind"`

I want to try something else that produce the same output as do.call(rbind, list) to check whither the problem is in my list or not.

example

```
       n = c(2, 3, 5,4) 
       n1 = c(2, 7, 4,6) 
       n2 = c(NA, NA, NA,NA) 
       x = list(n, n1, n2)
      dat <- do.call("rbind", x)
```

I tried this:

```
      df=matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x)), nrow= 3)
```

but

```
      identical(dat,df)
     > identical(dat,df)
      [1] FALSE
```

PS: I do not want to change the `class or str of my list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a note: Looking at

```
> dat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    3    5    4
[2,]    2    7    4    6
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    4   NA
[2,]    3    2    6   NA
[3,]    5    7   NA   NA
```

I am not surprised about the result that

```
identical(dat,df)
[1] FALSE
```

However, look at

```
df=matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x)), nrow= 3, byrow = T)
identical(dat,df)
[1] TRUE
```

**Alternatives to `do.call(rbind, list)`**

If you are looking for an alternative to `do.call`, look at `dplyr::bind_rows` (which feeds on dataframes and is quite efficient). A second alternative may be `Reduce`, as in:

```
Reduce(rbind, x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
init    2    3    5    4
        2    7    4    6
       NA   NA   NA   NA
```

A further alternative is `data.table::rbindlist`, which feeds on a list (!). Note though that the output will be transposed, meaning that each row will appear as one column. See

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(x))
   V1 V2 V3
1:  2  2 NA
2:  3  7 NA
3:  5  4 NA
4:  4  6 NA
```

You can wrap it into `t()` to transpose the result, though.

More generally speaking, though, if you want to check if all elements in your list have the same length, you might be more successful in finding the error with something like

```
sapply(x, length)
[1] 4 4 4
```

or depending on how your actual data looks like, a variation such as `ncol` or so instead of `length`. If the list elements have column names, then `names` might be a valid alternative as well.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `byrow = TRUE`:

```
df=matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x)), nrow= 3, byrow = TRUE)
```